# Events in an Angular 2 app in the model layer?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, eventemitter

I'm playing with Angular 2 and starting to build an app with it. I have components where I'm using binding between their views (.html) and their associated classes (.ts).

I'm also having a "model layer" where I'm modeling the business entities of my app. Right now, those models are plain-old TypeScript classes.

**What is the recommended way to have events or notifications in this model layer ?**

For example, I might have a Customer class that needs to signal to a CustomerTracker service that his Name property has changed.

What is the Angular 2 approach for doing that ? Should I be using EventEmitter (AFAIK, that's only for component), should I be using an Rx stream of events ?

Comment: `EventEmitter` is **only** for outputs in components and directives. Just use observables.

Comment: See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html